# Searching for pattern and printing the count

Tags: awk, sed

I have input table as below

```
module      input        output    type           func
AOIO        A1,A2,B       Z         comb        ((!A1+!A2) B)
AN2         A1,A2         ZN        comb        (A1 A2)
AIO         A1,A2,A3      Z          comb       ((A1 A2)+A3)
NOR         A1,A2 ,B       Z        comb       (!((A1 A2)+B))
BUF         I             Q          seq         I
CLK         I             QN         seq        IN
BND     
INV         IN            Z           comb      (!I)
```

I want above table to display in below format

```
module      input        output    type           func                 path
AOIO        A1,A2,B       Z         comb        ((!A1+!A2) B)           3
AN2         A1,A2         ZN        comb        (A1 A2)                 1
AIO         A1,A2,A3      Z          comb       ((A1 A2)+A3)            2
NOR         A1,A2 ,B       Z        comb       (!((A1 A2)+B))           3
BUF         I             Q          seq         I                      1
CLK         I             QN         seq        IN                      1
BND                                                                     0
INV         IN            Z           comb      (!I)                    1
```

The logic to get path is

> count the opening bracket '('.
>
> If `(` ends with `!` then assign path as `count+1` as in AO case.
> If it doesn't have `!` then assign path as count i.e only no.of opening bracket (AN,AI case). If it does not have opening bracket assign path as 1 (BUF,CLK case). If it doesn't have func, assign path as 0(BND case). If `!` is present between opening brackets `(` then ignore `!` and count the number of opening brackets and assign it to path (as in NOR case). And whenever there is `(!I)` present in func, assign path as 1 always.

Can anybody help me building logic for this.
I can count for ( using below code and gets value of no. of (  And then can check for above conditions using

```
sed 's/[^(]//g'  file  | awk '{ print length}  |  awk '{ if ($2~/^(*!/ ) print $3 length+1 ; elseif($2~/^( / ) print $3 length; elseif ($2 !~ /(/ print $3 "1"; elseif ($2~/(!I)/ ) print $3 "1"
```

But here in code i am not getting count of '( ' and getting error.
And I am not getting logic how can i count opening bracket if '!' is in between.

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Could you please do let us know about how count has become `3` in first line and became `2` in 2nd line? As its not clear in your question.

Comment: if start with ( and end with ! Then we will get no. of brackets '( ' + '1' . +1 is done to indicate that ' ! ' is at end of (.  So path we get is no.of ( +1 i.e 2 +1 =3 . In second it is starting with ( only one bracket so  we get as 1.

Comment: So it means `((((!` will become `5` then? And `((((((` will become 6 then? Kindly confirm once?

Comment: Starting with ( and ending with ! Basically means we will search for pattern start with ( and end with ! . And in that we will count the no. Of opening brackets and assign to path depending on condition.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13,  YES ```((((!``` Becomes ```5``` and ```((((((``` becomes ```6```. But if  '!'  is in between opening bracket like    ```(!(((```  then we will not add 1, jst count the no. Of opening bracket.  So for this ```(!(((```  it will become ```4``` which is no. of opening bracket only.

Comment: You never need sed when you're using awk, and piping awk to awk is rarely useful. `sed 's/[^(]//g'  file  | awk '{ print length}  |  awk '{foo}'` can be written as just one awk command, `awk '{gsub(/[^(]/,""); $0=length; foo}' file`

Comment: Is your real data that haphazardly spaced? If so, why? If not, please fix the spacing in your question so the columns align. Is that chains of blanks or tabs or both between your columns or are they supposed to be fixed width fields or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this awk as well:

```sh
cat cpath.awk
BEGIN {
    FS = " {3,}"
}
NR == 1 {
   printf "%-30s %s\n", $0, "path"
   next
}
{
    n = 0

    if ($2 ~ /!I|^[^(]+$/)
       n = 1
    else if (match($2, /^\(+![^(]/))
       n = RLENGTH -1
    else if (match($2, /^\([!(]*/)) {
       s = substr($2, 1, RLENGTH)
       n = gsub(/!$|\(/, "", s)
    }

    printf "%-30s %s\n", $0, n
}
```

Then ute it as:

```
awk -f cpath.awk file
```

```
module      input         output   type     func             path
AOIO        A1,A2,B       Z        comb     ((!A1+!A2) B)    3
AN2         A1,A2         ZN       comb     (A1 A2)          1
AIO         A1,A2,A3      Z        comb     ((A1 A2)+A3)     2
NOR         A1,A2 ,B      Z        comb     (!((A1 A2)+B))   3
BUF         I             Q        seq      I                1
CLK         I             QN       seq      IN               1
BND                                                          0
INV         IN            Z        comb     (!I)             1
```

Comment: it worked. But suppose I have func like ```(((A1 A2)+(B1)+C))``` here path value should come as ```3``` as there are 3 opening bracket. But using above code its giving ```4``` for thos func as its counting the ```B1``` opening bracket also. Then for this how can I modify the above code.

Comment: Yes it worked@anubhava. Slight modification will be there in code then it will display path column aligned  which has been completed by me. Thanks

Comment: Sir, the above code worked fine but when it comes to ```(!(!A1 !A2))``` here its ```not counting the ! of A1```( we need to count jst first ```!``` i.e of A1 not of A2) and giving path as 2 but the path should be 3.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** Adding solution since OP's samples are changed.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  OFS="\t"
  print $0,"path"
  next
}
{
  line=$0
  if($0~/!I/){
     print $0,1
     next
  }
  sub(/[^(]*/,"")
  sub(/[a-zA-Z0-9].*/,"")
  if($0~/!$/){
     print line,length($0)
  }
  else if(!NF){
     print line,length($0)+1
  }
  else if($0 ~ /!/ && $0 !~ /!$/){
     print line,length($0)-1
  }
  else{
     print line,length($0)
  }
}' Input_file | column  -t -s $'\t'
```

Output will be as follows.

```
module      input        output    type           func         path
AOIO        A1,A2,B       Z         comb        ((!A1+!A2) B)  3
AN2         A1,A2         ZN        comb        (A1 A2)        1
AIO         A1,A2,A3      Z          comb       ((A1 A2)+A3)   2
NOR         A1,A2 ,B       Z        comb       (!((A1 A2)+B))  3
BUF         I             Q          seq         I             1
CLK         I             QN         seq        IN             1
BND                                                            1
INV         IN            Z           comb      (!I)           1
```

---

---

Could you please try following, based on your shown samples only in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  OFS="\t"
  print $0,"path"
  next
}
{
  line=$0
  if($0~/!I/){
     print $0,1
     next
  }
  $1=""
  sub(/[^\t]*\t+/,"")
  sub(/[a-zA-Z0-9].*/,"")
  if($0~/!$/){
     print line,length($0)
  }
  else if(!NF){
     print line,length($0)+1
  }
  else if($0 ~ /!/ && $0 !~ /!$/){
     print line,length($0)-1
  }
  else{
     print line,length($0)
  }
}' Input_file | column  -t -s $'\t'
```

Output will be as follows.

```
module     func            path
AO         ((!A1+!A2) B)   3
AN         (A1 A2)         1
AI         ((A1 A2)+A3)    2
NOR        (!((A1 A2)+B))  3
BUF         I              1
CLK         IQ             1
BND                        0
INV        (!I)            1
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                   ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==1{                                 ##Checking condition if this is first line then do following.
  OFS="\t"                              ##Setting OFS as tab here.
  print $0,"path"                       ##Printing current line and path string here.
  next                                  ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  line=$0                               ##Setting variable line to current line.
  if($0~/!I/){                          ##Checking condition if line is equal to !I then do following.
     print $0,1                         ##Printing current line and 1 here.
     next                               ##next will skip all further statements from here.
  }
  $1=""                                 ##nullifying first field here.
  sub(/[^\t]*\t+/,"")                   ##Substituting everything till tab and tab occurrences with NULL here.
  sub(/[a-zA-Z0-9].*/,"")               ##Substituting everything till last in current line.
  if($0~/!$/){                          ##Checking if line do not end with ! then do following.
     print line,length($0)              ##Printing line and length of current line.
  }
  else if(!NF){                         ##else if number of fields is NULL then do following.
     print line,length($0)+1            ##Printing line and length of current line +1 here.
  }
  else if($0 ~ /!/ && $0 !~ /!$/){      ##else if line is NOT equal to ! AND not ending with !
     print line,length($0)-1            ##Printing line and length of current line-1 here.
  }
  else{                                 ##else do following.
     print line,length($0)              ##Printing line and length of current line.
  }
}' Input_file | column  -t -s $'\t'     ##Passing awk output to column command to separate it tab wise.
```

Comment: If in between my module and func there are 3 more columns present  as modified in question then will above code work jst by changing ```$1``` to ```$5```. Because I am getting ```1``` every where.

Comment: @NEHACHOUDHARY, for your given samples it worked for me fine, please do let me know in case of any queries here.

Comment: @NEHACHOUDHARY, yes please seeing your current examples you could change it to `$5` and it should fly then.

Comment: I changed it to ```$5``` but still i am getting ```1``` only.

Comment: @NEHACHOUDHARY, could you please try EDIT solution and let me know then?

Comment: @NEHACHOUDHARY, please check line `  sub(/[^(]*/,"")`.

Comment: Ok. If suppose func has data like this ```((A1 A2)) ,((!A1+A2)) ,(!((A1 A2))``` then path will be ```2, 3, 3```. In order to get this how can we modify the above code.

Comment: @NEHACHOUDHARY, Request you to NOT to keep changing your question(from very starting one), its NOT encouraged on SO because it confuses users, better you could a new question with your efforts by seeing answers from here, cheers.

Comment: this codes work fine but when it comes to ```(!(!A1 !A2))``` here its counting the ```! of A2 also``` and giving path as ```4 but path path should be 3```. We need to modify this line i think ```else if(!NF){         
     print line,length($0)+1``` to count only 1 first !